# Bash: Can anyone figure out the meaning of this line?

Tags: scripting, bash

```
cd $(dirname $(readlink -f $0))
```

It is part of a larger script file, but appears at the very beginning, right after #!/bin/bash

Comment: `man readlink`, `man cd`, and `man dirname` are your friends.

Comment: do `man readlink`, `man dirname`. `$0` is a variable that holds the name of the current script as it was invoked. A wild guess is that this line changes the cwd to the directory where the running script resides.

Answer (score 8):

This appears to change your shell's working directory to the directory where the script is stored. This is probably done so that the script can refer to other things in the same directory as itself.

I've used a variant of this before, `location=$(dirname $0)`. This does not change the directory, but rather stores the script's path for later use. `dirname $0` takes a filename (in this case, $0 or the path where the shell found that file), and `echo`es the directory that it is stored in. Wrapping a command (or a sequence of commands) in a `$()` combination causes the *output* of the command (whatever is printed to the screen by `echo`, `df`, `cat`, etc) to replace that expression using `$()`.
Example:
`variable=$(echo "test")`
becomes
`variable="test"`

As in other programming languages, `$()` can be nested. An example is:
`variable=$(echo $(echo "test"))`
The inner-most expression will print 'test', which will then be substituted as the argument to the outermost `echo`. The output of this `echo` will then be substituted as the value to store in `variable` - the result of the first and second example will be identical. A stupid example. but it works.

The only different between `$(dirname $(readlink -f $0))` and `$(dirname $0)` that I can see is that the former always returns the *absolute path*. The latter can return the relative path or the absolute path, depending on where the working directory is in relation to the script.

Comment: `Shouldn't this be on SO?` Shouldn't you have flagged it as off topic?

Comment: @user606723 I commented on the original question, referencing the `man` pages he could access for this information.

Comment: @user606723 I think this is the first answer I've ever seen get down-voted for too MUCH information.

Comment: @JedDaniels, perhaps, but I often go against the grain here on stackexchange. This question is "too simple" and in such case the reader should be given some vital hints, and made come to the conclusion on his own.

Comment: @user606723 - Just because something is simple *to you* doesn't mean it is simple to the person asking the question. Indeed `man` pages are often great for reminding you of things you already know, but less good if there is something you don't know (for instance you've been taught the backquote method of command substitution rather than the dollar-parentheses method and I see that no-one suggested `man bash`). Yes your attitude *is* against the grain here, we try to be civil and help people by answering their questions. Accusing an answer of being too *spoon-fed* is neither civil nor helpful.

Comment: I completely disagree. man pages are the perfect resource for learning things you don't know. I gave me all the hints that he needed to figure it out. The only information that was missing is what `readlink -f` did. If you think that thats too hard to look up in a man page for the first time, I'm not sure what to think of that. There is a difference between learning the entirety of bash via man pages and figuring out what `readlink -f` does. I wanted the OP to be able to learn how to connect the dots between each command and figure out what it did. I didn't withhold anything but the conclusion

Comment: I will add that I had no idea what `readlink -f` did when I saw this question. In fact, I'd never seen `readlink` before. But somehow I was able to look it up in `man readlink` and come to a conclusion of what the command did in about 20 seconds.

Comment: @user606723 - The point I was trying to make was that if you didn't know that `$(command)` resulted in the *command* being run and results of that command being substituted into the enclosing command, then knowing what `cd`, `dirname` and `readlink -f` do wouldn't help you. I already knew what all of these commands did, but I'd never seen dollar-parentheses method of command substitution, so had to look up the bash manual to find out - something no-one suggested or explained.

Comment: @MarkBooth, I would agree with that. But I didn't realize we were talking about ***that***. The post I thumbed down outright said the answer and then didn't explain it for the novice user at all. (Definition of spoonfeeding.) Seriously, go reread the answer. It's a bad answer from your argument as well.

Comment: Edited my answer to explain what `$()` is.

Answer (score 5):

- The command does `readlink -f $0`, which seems to return a path
- `dirname` takes that path, and gives you the dirname
- `cd` changes directory to that dirname
- `$0` is a variable that holds the name of the current script as it was
  invoked.

See:

- `man readlink`
- `man dirname`
- `man cd`

Comment: is downvoting a answer because of my comments on another question civil? hrm.

Comment: Although your *answer* gives the reader *almost* all of the information needed to work out what the answer is, it doesn't actually *answer the question*. Ultimately I didn't find this answer useful, so I marked it as such.

Comment: @MarkBooth, to be fair, the question is "can anyone figure out the meaning of this?"

Comment: The single word answer `Yes` would be *technically correct*, but not very useful, and would certainly result in an "Not an answer" flag from me.

Answer (score 3):

Adding to @user606723: `$0` contains the path and/or filename of the invoked script<sup>1</sup>. The `readlink -f $0` will make that path absolute and will also resolve any symlinks in this name - both intermediate directories and the final part also. From that part `dirname` will return only the directory part.

This is a good technique for writing "startup scripts" for applications. The script can be symlinked from some private `bin` directory **and** the script does not assume a certain install location of the application.

---

<sup>1</sup>The gory details about the contents of `$0`, when it is absolute, when not, when it contains a path or not and so on depend on the way the *calling* shell found the script. The comments shed some light on it.

Comment: Your description of $0 is wrong. It holds exactly what you typed as the "command" part of the command-line. For instance, if you type "./././././././myscript.sh", it would hold "./././././././myscript.sh". This is not a complete path, but a relative path formatted exactly as you typed it.

Comment: @user606723: Halfway correct: It contains the path where the _calling_ shell found the binary. This means, that `ls` will see `/bin/ls` even if called as `ll`. In any case `readlink -f` will make it absolute and without symlinks. Thats the important part.

Comment: Which means if you use a relative/absolute path, then it will contain exactly what you typed. If the shell used the $PATH variable, then it'll be what-you-typed + the path it was found in(which could be a relative path). Eitherway, it's not a complete path.

Comment: @user606723: Ah, I fixed the "complete" part.

Comment: This answer could be improved by editing the contents of the relevant comments into the answer itself rather than by referencing them.